# Cast a concatenation of a number and string to a date

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

Tried:

```
select concat(cast(201201 as string), '01');
```

Returns 20120101

However:

```
select to_date(concat(cast(201201 as string), '01'));
```

Returns null.

How can I tell hive to treat the result of `concat(cast(201201 as string), '01');` as a date, e.g. `select date_add(to_date(concat(cast(201201 as string), '01')), -365);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this with chained conversions . . . string to unix timestamp to timestamp to date:

```
select to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(concat(cast(201201 as string), '01'), 'YYYYMMDD')));
```

Answer (score 0):

The ‘CAST’ operator allows converting between compatible types. But the value needs to be acceptable as input to create a value of the target type.

So, I expect that a string is acceptable for cast to a DATE value, only if that string represents a date the same way it'd be for creating a literal DATE instance. Try standard ISO 8601 representation:

```sql
SELECT
    CAST(concat('2012-01', '-01') AS DATE) AS dolor_date
```

If the string value is in a different format, you may need to use other string manipulation functions to get the correct format:

```sql
SELECT
    CAST(
        concat(
            substring(lorem_string, 1, 4),
            '-',
            substring(lorem_string, 5, 2),
            '-',
            substring(lorem_string, 7, 2) )
        AS DATE) AS dolor_date
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, Within my larger query I'll be selecting a field of the format YYYYMM e.g. 201201 so not sure how to add in the dash '-' or even make the first component of concat a string?

Comment: SQL usually allows cast without the dashes  - 20120101 should cast to date OK. Hive may be different, but it is worth trying.

Comment: Tried ```select cast(concat(201201, '01') as date);``` but got Null. Thanks all the same